# Append a new function in grails remotefunction

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

In the below code, I am loading a template over a div, on changing the combo box. I am supposed to append the template over the previously selected template, instead of replacing the div contents accordingly.

```
               <g:select id="paymentTypeUid" 
                         name='paymentTypeUid' 
                         value="${paymentTypeDesc}" 
                         from='${paymentType}'
                         optionKey="paymentTypeDesc" 
                         optionValue="paymentTypeDesc"
                         onchange="${ remoteFunction( 
                        controller :'payment',
                     action:'selectedPaymentType',                  
                      update:'divBeneIns',                               
                    params:'\'paymentType=\'+this.value',
                    after: 'welcome();',
                    onSuccess: 'reinitialiseScrollPane();'                                                      
                   )}"                           
                   />
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you rephrase you question? to me it is not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: same to me to0 ? add those div code if possible?